# Capture screen of GLSurfaceView to bitmap

Tags: java, android, screen-capture, glsurfaceview

I need to be able to capture an image of a `GLSurfaceView` at certain moment in time. I have the following code:

```
relative.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(relative.getDrawingCache());
relative.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
Log.v(TAG, "Screenshot height: " + screenshot.getHeight());
image.setImageBitmap(screenshot);
```

The `GLSurfaceView` is contained within a `RelativeLayout`, but I have also tries it straight using the `GLSurfaceView` to try and capture the image. With this I think the screen captures a transparent image, i.e. nothing there. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi there I am experiencing same problem did you find any solution if so please share, thanks.

Comment: I did not find an answer to this question sorry.

Comment: Are you rendering continuously??

Comment: @SamRowley.. did u find any solution?
if yes then kindly tell me on this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531481/cocos-2d-screen-shot-is-black-in-android

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`SurfaceView` and `GLSurfaceView` punch holes in their windows to allow their surfaces to be displayed. In other words, they have transparent areas.

So you cannot capture an image by calling `GLSurfaceView.getDrawingCache()`.

If you want to get an image from `GLSurfaceView`, you should invoke `gl.glReadPixels()` in `GLSurfaceView.onDrawFrame()`.

I patched `createBitmapFromGLSurface` method and call it in `onDrawFrame()`.

(The original code might be from [skuld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839992/skuld)'s code.)

```
private Bitmap createBitmapFromGLSurface(int x, int y, int w, int h, GL10 gl)
        throws OutOfMemoryError {
    int bitmapBuffer[] = new int[w * h];
    int bitmapSource[] = new int[w * h];
    IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.wrap(bitmapBuffer);
    intBuffer.position(0);

    try {
        gl.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, intBuffer);
        int offset1, offset2;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            offset1 = i * w;
            offset2 = (h - i - 1) * w;
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                int texturePixel = bitmapBuffer[offset1 + j];
                int blue = (texturePixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                int red = (texturePixel << 16) & 0x00ff0000;
                int pixel = (texturePixel & 0xff00ff00) | red | blue;
                bitmapSource[offset2 + j] = pixel;
            }
        }
    } catch (GLException e) {
        return null;
    }

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSource, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```

Comment: You can put `createBitmapFromGLSurface` in your GLSurfaceView's subclass. Calling it in `onDraw()` is important.

Comment: But in onDraw you don't have an instance of gl. How can you retrieve it?

Comment: (after 6 minutes) I will answer myself, this method should be called from onDrawFrame() of the renderer and not from onDraw().
You can find the implementation here: https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage

Comment: @Dalvik you're right. It's my mistake. I've to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why; however I removed all calls for saving the colors and instead just have `int pixel = (texturePixel & 0xffffffff);` - Your combination was giving far too much of a blue hue. Thank you again!

Comment: I could get the screen shot of camera view, with no overlay image which was on top it? any idea what needs to be fixed ?

Comment: Can you please try to resolved my this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601187/how-to-save-bitmap-from-glsurfaceview-only-bitmap-not-whole-texture

Comment: Hi Dalinaum! This works very good. However I wonder if I could do something to reduce the lag caused by process of capturing. On Samsung   S6 it takes around 3 seconds, surface freezes for this time of course. Do you think there is any way to decrease this time, or (even better) do this asynchronously? I would appreciate your thought on this. Best regards.

Comment: @Nativ could you explain how you implement above code(method) in android-gpuimage(GPUImageRenderer class) to get bitmap from glsurfaceview.

Comment: @KrzysztofKansy, I made an edit for a more optimized version, and yes, it could be done asynchronously with the standard Android libraries for background processes. Additionally you could make it quick by dividing the work in half and having 2 threads work on it.

Comment: Problem is default CameraPreview implementation uses SurfaceView, NOT GLSurfaceView so there's no way to use it in such case.

Comment: Where do I get `x` and `y` from?

Answer (score 22):

Here is a complete solution if you are using a third party library that you just 'pass in' a GLSurfaceView defined in your layout. You won't have a handle on the onDrawFrame() of the renderer, this can be a problem...

To do this you need to queue it up for the GLSurfaceView to handle.

```
private GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView; // findById() in onCreate
private Bitmap snapshotBitmap;

private interface BitmapReadyCallbacks {
    void onBitmapReady(Bitmap bitmap);
}

/* Usage code
   captureBitmap(new BitmapReadyCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onBitmapReady(Bitmap bitmap) {
            someImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
   });
*/

// supporting methods
private void captureBitmap(final BitmapReadyCallbacks bitmapReadyCallbacks) {
    glSurfaceView.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            EGL10 egl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();
            GL10 gl = (GL10)egl.eglGetCurrentContext().getGL();
            snapshotBitmap = createBitmapFromGLSurface(0, 0, glSurfaceView.getWidth(), glSurfaceView.getHeight(), gl);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    bitmapReadyCallbacks.onBitmapReady(snapshotBitmap);
                }
            });

        }
    });

}

// from other answer in this question
private Bitmap createBitmapFromGLSurface(int x, int y, int w, int h, GL10 gl) {

    int bitmapBuffer[] = new int[w * h];
    int bitmapSource[] = new int[w * h];
    IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.wrap(bitmapBuffer);
    intBuffer.position(0);

    try {
        gl.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, intBuffer);
        int offset1, offset2;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            offset1 = i * w;
            offset2 = (h - i - 1) * w;
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                int texturePixel = bitmapBuffer[offset1 + j];
                int blue = (texturePixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                int red = (texturePixel << 16) & 0x00ff0000;
                int pixel = (texturePixel & 0xff00ff00) | red | blue;
                bitmapSource[offset2 + j] = pixel;
            }
        }
    } catch (GLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "createBitmapFromGLSurface: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSource, w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** In this code, when I click the Button, it takes the screenshot as Image and saves it in sdcard location. I used boolean condition and an `if` statement in `onDraw` method, because the renderer class may call the `onDraw` method anytime and anyway, and without the `if` this code may save lots of images in the memory card.

MainActivity class:

```
protected boolean printOptionEnable = false;

saveImageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v("hari", "pan button clicked");
        isSaveClick = true;
        myRenderer.printOptionEnable = isSaveClick;
    }
});
```

MyRenderer class:

```
int width_surface , height_surface ;

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    Log.i("JO", "onSurfaceChanged");
    // Adjust the viewport based on geometry changes,
    // such as screen rotation
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    float ratio = (float) width / height;

    width_surface =  width ;
    height_surface = height ;
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    try {
        if (printOptionEnable) {
            printOptionEnable = false ;
            Log.i("hari", "printOptionEnable if condition:" + printOptionEnable);
            int w = width_surface ;
            int h = height_surface  ;

            Log.i("hari", "w:"+w+"-----h:"+h);

            int b[]=new int[(int) (w*h)];
            int bt[]=new int[(int) (w*h)];
            IntBuffer buffer=IntBuffer.wrap(b);
            buffer.position(0);
            GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h,GLES20.GL_RGBA,GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
            for(int i=0; i<h; i++)
            {
                //remember, that OpenGL bitmap is incompatible with Android bitmap
                //and so, some correction need.        
                for(int j=0; j<w; j++)
                {
                    int pix=b[i*w+j];
                    int pb=(pix>>16)&0xff;
                    int pr=(pix<<16)&0x00ff0000;
                    int pix1=(pix&0xff00ff00) | pr | pb;
                    bt[(h-i-1)*w+j]=pix1;
                }
            }           
            Bitmap inBitmap = null ;
            if (inBitmap == null || !inBitmap.isMutable()
                || inBitmap.getWidth() != w || inBitmap.getHeight() != h) {
                inBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            }
            //Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            inBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
            //return inBitmap ;
            // return Bitmap.createBitmap(bt, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            inBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bt, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
            inBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bos); 
            byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
            ByteArrayInputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata);

            final Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
            long mytimestamp=c.getTimeInMillis();
            String timeStamp=String.valueOf(mytimestamp);
            String myfile="hari"+timeStamp+".jpeg";

            dir_image = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+
            "printerscreenshots"+File.separator+"image");
            dir_image.mkdirs();

            try {
                File tmpFile = new File(dir_image,myfile); 
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            fis.close();
            fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.v("hari", "screenshots:"+dir_image.toString());
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GLTextureView extending TextureView instead of GlsurfaceView to show you OpenGL data.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061419/converting-from-glsurfaceview-to-textureview-via-gltextureview

As the GLTextureView extends from TextureView, it has a getBitmap function that should work.

```
myGlTextureView.getBitmap(int width, int height)
```