# Draw background on a bitmap where i'm going to draw a view that i'm going to export to a file

Tags: android, canvas, view, bitmap, drawable

I'm exporting my view into a file.

My problem is that I'm using Holo Light theme but the file exported has a dark background.

The code:

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(totalWidth, totalHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(b);
miVista.draw(mCanvas);          
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
```

I've tried a lot of things to paint it in another color than black like `drawcolor`, `setpixels`, etc, but I can't find the correct answer to my problem.

[Link to the picture with what you can see in the terminal](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Ph9F5sPUWNU/UT7gify4eDI/AAAAAAAAE0o/KrdfZ5mLpvE/s651/CapturaPantalla.PNG).

[Link to the exported picture](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ZMJjxXP1jl8/UT7giQnxpeI/AAAAAAAAE0s/t5p4DgVRJF4/s628/Ju_2013_03_12_07_48_38.png)

Comment: Could you maybe show us an image (screenshot) of what do you want and what do you get at the moment?

Comment: I added two links to the pictures (I need reputation 10 to put the images). I think I'm looking for a simple solution, and perhaps, it can't be as easy as I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution in this other post:
[Convert view to bitmaps...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536066/convert-view-to-bitmap-on-android?rq=1)

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(totalWidth, totalHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(b);
Drawable bgDrawable =miVista.getBackground();
if (bgDrawable!=null) 
    bgDrawable.draw(mCanvas);
else 
    mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
miVista.draw(mCanvas);
```

The solution it's to use a Drawable object...

Answer (score 1):

Clear the canvas for example with

```
mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
```

then it will have white background. What kind of background do you expect?

Comment: I'm afraid that Canvas object doesn't have clear method. This is not about of the background that I expect, it's about the background I want ;). My problem is that because I use Holo Light theme the colors of the views are dark. So, the result that I achieve with a black background it's not good.

Comment: uh, I meant drawColor, sorry.

Comment: so if you first use drawColor(Color.WHITE), then draw your View (miVista) onto the same canvas, it still comes out as black?

Comment: I don't know why, but yes, that's what happens.