# How to dynamically add text over the image?

Tags: java, android, image, text, dynamic

I have to put the text over the image, I want to get the following final result:

[image: Example result]

I list all images from my database and add them dynamically to my Flexbox.
But I need to do this by code, dynamically.

Comment: You can take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002503/android-add-text-to-picture-and-save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<RelativeLayout> 
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/myImageSouce" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Default text"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

And dynamically change Text in this image using:

```
TextView myAwesomeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myImageViewText);

myAwesomeTextView.setText("New Text inside Image");
```

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a LinearLayout dynamically  :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use Canvas to draw the Image and draw the text at the bottom o canvas. Check [Developer Google](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing)