# How to create wallet in android using page curl animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, user-interface, page-curl

I have to create this type of layout images are coming from server,images are countless,
at first moment i have 5 imageview to show these five coupons.but when images are more 
than five then i have to use a page curl animation to set left images like this.

[image]

This snap is the after page curl.but i don't know how to implement this thing. Any helping 
hands will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Same has been implemented in iPhone application.. So I am looking for help in an Android application.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be the best library available to do this: https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl But you will probably have to modify it so you can change the source textures at runtime.

Comment: ya i already seen this one,but i don't get any logic to change in that.

Comment: There's an example in that project called CurlActivity. You're supposed to subclass PageProvider for your activity as shown there. You could do something like this in the loadBitmap method of your PageProvider to get the view you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9595919/506796 Use the index parameter to determine which view to draw to the bitmap's canvas. Then the CurlView can overlay your actual content.