# Get screenshot from yandex map kit

Tags: android, yandex-maps

I have `yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView`. I want to create the screenshot from it.

How can I get screenshot from yandex map kit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways.

First one is using [the static Yandex map API](https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/staticapi/1.x/dg/concepts/input_params-docpage/) (sometimes you aren't need to use complex Mapkit):

[`http://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?lang=ru-RU&ll=32.810152,39.889847&size=450,450&z=10&l=map`](http://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?lang=en-US&ll=32.810152,39.889847&size=450,450&z=10&l=map)

The second way is drawing `MapView` into `Bitmap` and [it's not difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9595919/1348726).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used first solution. Second solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wanna use static Yandex map API, you can use `MapView.getScreenshot()` method.

Also, if this method returns null, well, in short, you should try adding xml attribute`app:movable="true"` to your MapView.