# Use a view instead of Marker in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

Its possible to use a custom view instead of a Marker in Google Maps API v2?
It's sad that Google doesn't allow us to customize our markers with views (Relative layout with imageviews, textviews etc) , so its possible to inflate a view and then put that view to a specific position in a map?

Comment: Since they can use Drawables, I'm going to have to ask - `What have you tried?`

Comment: I know they can use drawables, but i want to use Views in fact. RelativeLayouts, ImageViews, TextView, etc.

Comment: What i have gone so far is build my view, transform that view into a bitmap, and set to marker. But this appears to be so wrong to me. hahaha

Comment: +1, clever. Since that's the only way it can work right now, because Markers use Bitmaps. Additionally, consider the use-case of having 20 markers on the screen/map at the same time. With 20 drawables that's not alot. With 20 dialog-like views... I dunno. It may get cluttered on phones.

Comment: For example, if you see AirBnb app, they seem to use a view on that. You open the map, then you can see the prices in a baloon, and if you select a place in the bottom viewpager, the marker update its view to a highlighted mode.

Comment: Are we sure they're not 'faking' a click on the Marker to open it's context menu? :) Their context menus/dialogs can be Fragments. (from what I see from my code)

Comment: Did you try to use views above the map (not as marker)?

Comment: The problem to use views is that if you move the map...the views will not move and we cannot know the lat lng in the map.

Comment: Add listener to map, handle moving event, convert lat/lon to screen pixels and update views position.

Answer (score 10):

You can use IconGenerator to achieve this.

```
IconGenerator iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(context);
iconGenerator.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_custom_marker));
View inflatedView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.marker_custom, null);
iconGenerator.setContentView(inflatedView);
Marker marker = map.addMarker(
        new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(-34.397, 150.644))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconGenerator.makeIcon())));
```

Now we need that `marker_custom` view and `bg_custom_marker` drawable.

**marker_custom.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <TextView
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I'm a custom view :)" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**bg_custom_marker.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />
</shape>
```

It looks like the following:

[image: Custom Marker]

Edit: `iconGenerator.setBackground(null);` might be more flexiable.

Answer (score 5):

Well you can not put view on Google Maps but @WitaloBenicio said you can convert that view to Bitmap and show it on marker

[SO : Convert View to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536066/convert-view-to-bitmap-on-android)
and using
[BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap (Bitmap image)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#customize_the_marker_image) add to marker

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()..icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)));
```

**I strongly prefer go to this library** 
[Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) and check for `IconGenerator` class [Git Repo](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)

Comment: This lib will be usefull. Thanks

Comment: p.s.: im Witalo Benicio. hahahaha

Comment: I wanted to edit this question because of credit to skadoosh for mentioning IconGenerator class. The best way is to show view on Marker using IconGenerator.setContentView() method - http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/ui/IconGenerator.html#setContentView-View- and then invoke IconGenerator.makeIcon()

Comment: @skadoosh, how to handle click different component of view?

Comment: @Suman Never tried and I believe you can not, As we are displaying a image over map.

Comment: if  I use custom view where 3 or 4 button, can I handle click event of this buttons?

Comment: @Sumam not sure about but if you adding those buttons to a single view and the whole is a marker then on marker click listener is called not view click listener.

Comment: What if view has animation? if we convert each frame to bmp to get animated effect for marker, it is not that much smooth. What is best approach for that?