# Use composable instead of marker in google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I know it's possible to use a custom view instead of a basic map marker in Google Maps doing what's described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35793743/7900721). I was curious if it was possible to achieve a similar affect with Compose?

Since `ComposeView` is a final class, couldn't extend that directly so I was thinking of having a `FrameLayout` that could add it as a child. Although this seems to be causing a race condition since composables draw slightly differently from normal android `View`s.

```
class MapMarkerView : FrameLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        initView()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        initView()
    }

    private fun initView() {
        val composeView = ComposeView(context).apply {
            layoutParams = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        }
        composeView.setContent {
            // this runs asynchronously making the the bitmap generation not include composable at runtime?
            Text(text = "2345", modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Green, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)))
        }
        addView(composeView)
    }

}
```

Most articles I have read have some callback function for generating a bitmap like [this](https://proandroiddev.com/create-bitmaps-from-jetpack-composables-bdb2c95db51) which wouldn't necessarily work in this use case where each view is generated dynamically and needed to be converted to a bitmap right away for the map.

Answer (score 0):

The `MapMarkerView` you are attempting to create is an indirect child of `ViewGroup`. `ComposeView` is also an indirect child of `ViewGroup` which means you can directly substitute a `ComposeView` in places where you intend to use this class. The `ComposeView` class is not meant to be subclassed. The only thing you really need to be concerned with as a developer is its `setContent` method.

```
val composeView: View = ComposeView(context).apply{
   setContent {
       Text(text = "2345", modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Green, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)))
   }
}
```

Now you can replace the `MapMarkerView` with this `composeView` in your code or even use it at any location where a `View` or any of it's subclasses is required.

Comment: This is a good point as far as not needing to have a wrapper FrameLayout, although this still won't solve the async nature of compose when trying to generate a bitmap when making a custom google map marker.

Comment: hey @AndrewSteinmetz were you able to find a way to use Composable func and turn it into a MapMarker?