# Saved bitmap is just blank file

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

In my application, I'am drawing on Canvas. When user clicks on save icon, I retrieve a bitmap canvas is drawing on and save it as PNG file. Everything works fine except that the picture is blank. When saved as JPEG, it's just full black.

Canvas code

```
private Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH);

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    float x;
    float y;

    for(int i = table.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        x = table[i][0];       
        y = table[i][1];
        alpha = (int) table[i][2];

        paint.setAlpha(alpha);
        canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint);
    }
}
```

Activity just calls AsyncTask so I won't post it here.
Here is AsyncTask

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
    Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;

    String filename = name + ".png";
    String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();

    File file = new File(dir, filename);

    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (outStream != null) {
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

And this is what should be in the picture
[image]

**EDIT**

Added onDraw() method

Comment: can you put your ondraw() method

Comment: Can you explain how you are expecting your "canvas code" to work?  I'm having a hard time figuring out what you're intending to do there.  Also, your AsyncTask seems completely unrelated to your canvas code.

Comment: Well, I am just drawing points from table. I have set `bitmap` as Bitmap that Canvas is drawing onto. So I assumed that when I save `bitmap` as picture, those points will be visible.
There's no problem with code, I only don't understand why, when I save that bitmap as a picture, the picture is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do create your own Canvas in your custom view and draw in it:

```
mCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

and in your ondraw()

```
mCanvas.drawPoint(parm1, parm2, param3);
```

The problem is that you don't draw on the right canvas.

Comment: That part is going just fine. I can't use `drawPoints(...)` becouse I need to change `paint` every iteration. And problem is not with drawing, but with the picture I get when I save the `bitmap` onto which is Canvas drawing. The picture is just blank, without those points I draw there.

Comment: what I want to say is that your drawing on the wrong canvas. Why you say you can't use drawPoint() ? you use it in your code. You are drawing on the canvas that onDraw give you, so it is detach from your bitmap

Comment: So when I want the displayed bitmap I need to get that view's Bitmap?

Comment: Yep, when the guy click on the button, you return your bitmap (view.getBitmap()).

Comment: Alright, the problem was exactly what you suggested. I used this as reference to correct it http://stackoverflow.com/a/9595919/5465676 . Thank you! I will accept your answer when you edit it, now it's not clear what the solution is.