# How to save RoundedBitmapDrawable

Tags: android, drawable, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory, roundedbitmapdrawable

I want to change a shape of image from square to round. And after that I am planning to save this bitmap. But i faced with problem I can't cast RoundedBitmapDrawable to Bitmap? Or may be exist another way for saving RoundedBitmapDrawable instance to SD card.

```
 void setImage(){
    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.user);
    mImageView.setImageDrawable(createNewBitmap(mBitmap));
    mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    //after that i am planning save bitmap
}

Drawable createNewBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){

RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(),bitmap);
    roundedBitmapDrawable.setCornerRadius(bitmapRadius);
    roundedBitmapDrawable.setAntiAlias(true);
    return roundedBitmapDrawable;
}
```

Comment: Are you using any view to show this round bitmap?

Comment: Kanak Sony no, only ImageView.

Comment: You can save Bitmap from ImageView directly.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. What method do you suggest?

Comment: Can you share any piece of code you tried?

Comment: I change my question to add a piece of code. I tried different methods but the method above one of them.

Comment: try this once - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536066/convert-view-to-bitmap-on-android

Comment: Kanak Sony thank you! It's work fine!