# UI Automator - Get background color at XY coordinates

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

Is there a way to get the color of the exact place on-screen using UI Automator?

Real case problem: some button changes the screen background color. I need to reach background property somehow using UI Automator. Searching in documentation and source code didn't bring any results.

Some workarounds and hacks acceptable.

Comment: Do you need the color of the background, even if there is something on top of it at those coordinates?

Comment: @RyanM I need to find out if there's a way to fetch color of the top-layer at a specific XY point

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your view to bitmap using [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536066/convert-view-to-bitmap-on-android)

Then on the `Bitmap` call `getPixel(x,y)` and get the Color of the pixel on that position.

```
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(100,100);
Color color = Color.valueOf(pixel);
color.alpha();
color.red();
color.green();
color.blue();
```

Comment: Good approach, although there's a problem. I can't access View directly. Anyway, bounty is yours since no better solutions proposed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I saw a video of a YouTuber who used python to read RGB values from points on the screen of his monitor in real time.

https://youtu.be/aosN_FvW2e4

Python outputs values to the console though, so you can only use this to test your app on an emulator