# Android Canvas Paint: getTextBounds() ignores system font

Tags: java, android, kotlin, fonts, paint

```
paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length, textBounds)
...
canvas.drawText(text, canvas.width/2F - textBounds.exactCenterX(), canvas.height/2F - textBounds.exactCenterY(), paint)
```

I am using `getTextBounds()` to center text in a circle graphic. And while it looks fine with the system's default font (**left screenshot**), the text slides to the left of the circle center when I change the system font (**right screenshot**):

[image]
[image]

The `103` and `234` look particularly bad to me. The font I chose is `Choco Cooky` on a Samsung Galaxy S7.

I put a debug print after the titular line of code and discovered it returns the same bounds **regardless of typeface chosen**, which would explain the result since the letters of `Choco Cooky` are smaller. However this behavior seems like a bug to me.

---

**What can I do to get an accurate measurement of a text's bounds that respects the system font?**

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to use a `TextView` with a `ShapeDrawable` as background, which then gets [converted into a Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536066/convert-view-to-bitmap-on-android) so it can be used as a Google Maps marker. However this sounds like a lot of rewriting without any guarantee it will fix the issue.