# Take a screenshot of a specific LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, screenshot, android-bitmap

I am trying to take a screenshot of a LinearLayout that has an image view inside and take a screenshot of that image, but when I press the button it takes a screenshot of the entire screen and I would like to save just the LinearLayout with the image inside since I've been looking for a solution for almost 2 days

The code used:

```
 LinearLayout ll;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meme, container, false);
        Button downloadButton = view.findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);
        ll = view.findViewById(R.id.rootView);

        downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
                saveBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });

 return view;

}

public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {

        View rootView=ll.getRootView();
        rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return rootView.getDrawingCache();

    }
    public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "SCREEN"
                    + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"));
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.MemesFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ProfileActivity">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/downloadButton"
            android:layout_width="41dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/download"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rootView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/memeRandomView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">
            </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>
        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the view to Bitmap like this

Ref:[Convert view to bitmap on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536066/convert-view-to-bitmap-on-android)

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Bind a canvas to it
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        //Get the view's background
        Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable!=null) 
            //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else 
            //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        // draw the view on the canvas
        view.draw(canvas);
        //return the bitmap
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

Then use this Bitmap and save it in external like you have.

Comment: I  replaced Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();  to Drawable bgDrawable=view.getForeground(); and it was success, thanks for good code!

Answer (score 0):

Or more simplified:

```
View rootView = findViewById(R.id.memeRandomView).getRootView();
```

or

```
View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.memeRandomView);
```

You are welcome! :)