# Android screenshot not capturing everything

Tags: android, screenshot, arcore, screen-capture

I am using the [HelloAR demo application](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/quickstart) and I am trying to take a screenshot of the entire screen (menu bar and everything). I am able to take a screenshot, but not everything is captured... GUI elements are visible in the screenshot, but the camera feed is not.

Here is my code:

```
int counter = 0;
private void takeScreenShot()
{
    View view = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    PixelCopy.request(getWindow(), bmp, copyResult -> {
        if(copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS){
            String filename = getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + "SCREENSHOTS" + File.seperator + "SS_" + counter + ".png";
            store(bmp, filename);
            counter++;
        }
    }, new Handler());
}

public static void storeit(Bitmap bm, String fileName){
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is what the screenshot looks like:

[image]

How can I capture the entire screen (camera feed, UI elements, menu bar, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `MediaProjection` to capture the screen contents.
This has the drawback of requesting the user for screen sharing permission.
([Reference SO answer with example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34549690/11016588))

Alternatively, you could get the content of the `GLSurfaceView` using `glReadPixels` fn & superimpose your existing View image over it.
([Reference SO answer with example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12899426/11016588))

---

The reason your current implementation doesn't work is because

`SurfaceView` and `GLSurfaceView` punch holes in their windows to allow their surfaces to be displayed ([Android src reference](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/SurfaceView.java#538)). In other words, they have transparent areas.
So you cannot capture an image by calling `GLSurfaceView.getDrawingCache()`.

If you want to get an image from GLSurfaceView, you should invoke `glReadPixels()` in `GLSurfaceView.onDrawFrame()`.

Comment: Thanks, but any idea why the approach I am taking does not work? Why are only some of the contents captured?

Comment: Basically, `GLSurfaceView` doesn't draw its own contents, it literally has an empty space which is rendered into by the `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`. Take a look at the links I've shared in my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, that is more clear. However, if I capture the GLSurfaceView, then will that include the UI elements and the top menu bar?

Comment: If by capture, you mean the `glReadPixels()` , then No. You'll only get the content being displayed in the `GLSurfaceView` , but you should be able to superimpose your existing image (generated using `PixelCopy`) on the surface view image to get your required image.

Comment: Superimposing should be fairly simple (assuming width & height are the same), create a new bitmap, use `Canvas.drawBitmap()` to draw the old images in the new bitmap.
([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41221134/11016588))